# Calculating mode in C — the math is a bit wrong

Tags: c, mode

3rd day of C programming so bear with me. I'm doing a beginner's exercise in which I generate random numbers and calculate the mean, std dev., median, and mode.

Problems in the mode. I'm moving on to work on some other projects but in the meantime I'm posting this to see if anyone can spot my error. The user inputs, at the beginning, the range of the random numbers and the quantity of them. The mode returns a correct value if the minimum is 1, but not if the minimum is larger.

Will also be interesting if there are any insights into how to allow for more than one mode — I've an approximate idea how to do it (an extra for loop and an extra array? but not quite sure how I'd handle printing only the relevant values from the new array).

Here's (only the relevant portions of) my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {

    // setting parameters 
    int SIZE, MIN, MAX;
    printf("How low should the smallest random number be?\n");
    scanf("%d",&MIN);
    printf("How high should the largest random number be?\n");
    scanf("%d",&MAX);
    printf("How many random numbers do you want?\n");
    scanf("%d",&SIZE);

    int rnx[SIZE]; 
    int biggles, *tally, count=0;
    int mode;
    int i,j;
    float mean, sumdev, median;

    tally = (int*) calloc (MAX-MIN,sizeof(int)); // creates an array for the tally in the mode function and initializes it to zero for the incrementing.

    srand(time(NULL)); // random seed outside the loop

  // generate random numbers into an array

  for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++) {
    rnx[i]=round(((double)rand()/(RAND_MAX)*(MAX-MIN)+MIN));
  }

  BubbleSort(rnx,SIZE); //  left out for brevity the actual function I wrote for this but it works

  // calculates the mode

  for(i=MIN;i<MAX;i++) {
      for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++) {
          if(rnx[j]==i) {
              tally[i-MIN]++; // in the second array we register how many times each number occurs in the random sequence, checking from the minimum to maximum.
          }
      }
  }
  mode = biggles;
  // for (j=0;j<10;j++) {
  for(i=MIN;i<MAX;i++) {
      if(tally[i-MIN]>count) {
          count=tally[i-MIN];
          if(count>1) {
              mode=i-MIN+1; }
      }
  } 

  if (mode!=biggles) {
    printf("The mode of the random numbers is %d\n",mode); }
  else { printf("The random numbers have no mode.\n"); } // in case there is no mode. but what if there is more than one?
  free(tally);
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that `biggles` is never initialized, so when you do `mode = biggles;` you set `mode` to a completely random value. (Also, `biggles` is not a descriptive or meaningful name.)

Comment: indentation needs fixing too.  Also, "no mode" means an empty list.  That's probably not the best way to check for it.  If you have at least a single number, you have at least a single mode.

Comment: @Patashu 'indeterminate' would be a better word choice than 'completely random'.

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

`tally = (int*) calloc (MAX-MIN,sizeof(int));`

Say MAX is 4, MIN is 1. That means you can get 1, 2, 3 and 4 as random numbers. But MAX - MIN = 3, so you allocate space for only 3. Change this to MAX-MIN+1.

The next problem is this line.

`round(((double)rand()/(RAND_MAX)*(MAX-MIN)+MIN));`

Again say MAX is 4, MIN is 1. This will produce values anywhere from 1 (`round(0*(4-1)+1)`) to 4 (`round(1*(4-1)+1)`) correctly. However, 1 to 1.5 will become 1, whereas 1.5 to 2.5 will become 2, similarly only 3.5 to 4 will become 4. So 1 and 4 are half as likely as other numbers.

To solve this, try this instead

`floor(((double)rand()/(RAND_MAX+1)*(1+MAX-MIN)+MIN));`

This will range from 1 to 4 still but give all possibilities equal opportunity. (The RAND_MAX+1 part is to make sure it doesn't generate a 5 with very tiny probability)

This is how I would calculate mode (untested):

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
{
    tally[rnx[i]-MIN] += 1;
}

int modecount = 0;
int mode = -1;
for (i = 0; i <= MAX-MIN; ++i) //<= instead of < because MAX is inclusive, not exclusive
{
    if (tally[i] > modecount)
    {
        mode = i+MIN;
        modecount = tally[i];
    }
}
```

In pseudocode:

1) Create the array, tally, with the count of how many random numbers were that number in each index.

2) Look for the largest entry in tally and note its position and count.

Then, to handle multiple modes:

Once you have gone through `tally` entirely and found the mode, scan `tally` looking for every entry with the same count as the highest count that you found for your mode. All of those will be modes, you can print them out as you find them if you don't want to allocate another array to store them.